# Writing information from Combo-box to text file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, combobox

I am trying to right the information from a combobox into a text file so it can be saved. If the information in the combobox is John, Marry, Jack I would like it to appear in the text file like this:

```
John
Mary
Jack
```

The code I currently use give a result of JohnMaryJack in the text file

```
For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
        Dim test As String
        test = item
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}", item)
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Documents\test.txt"
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
            objWriter.Write(test)
            objWriter.WriteLine()
            objWriter.Close()
            MsgBox("Text written to file")
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If

    Next
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Does `sb.AppendFormat("{0} ", item)` work?

Comment: Sorry everyone, The formatting was wrong i need then one under the other (Fixed now)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load from file into listbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273426/load-from-file-into-listbox)

Comment: the question Load from file into listbox has answer not both saving and loading to/from listbox. Wich is excatly the same as when working with comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would take the writing to the file out of the For Each-loop. This way you only write to the file once.
Second you can slightly adapt the answer of @BiggsTRC to

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
```

Furthermore you use the variable `test` to write to the textfile, instead of the stringbuilder you used. This way the formating never gets into the file.

So than your piece of code looks something like this:

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder()

For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
        'Dim test As String
        'test = item
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
Next

Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Documents\test.txt"
If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
    objWriter.Write(sb.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
    objWriter.WriteLine()
    objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

There could be some syntax-minor error in it, cause it's a long time I've written VB and I haven't a VS present at the moment, but I think you get the picture ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change this line:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0}", item)
```

To be like this:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0}\r\n", item)
```

(notice the space after the {0})

This will give you a space after each person's name so that you will end up with one name per line with a return after the last line.

Comment: Sorry, The formatting was wrong i need then one under the other (Fixed now)

Comment: It returns this in my text document, John\r\nHello\r\nYou\r\nMust\r\nDie\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(filename, (From p As String In cmbworld.Items).ToArray)
```