# Follow up Writing information from combo box to text file

Tags: vb.net, combobox, streamwriter

with reference to this help topic

[Writing information from Combo-box to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352588/writing-information-from-combo-box-to-text-file)

i cannot figure out how to get it to not **add** a space after each entry

eg

John
Mary
Joe

instead of

John_
Mary_
Joe_

How do I get it just write the entry

code in question

```
Dim sb as new StringBuilder()

For Each item As Object In cmbworld.Items
    'Dim test As String
    'test = item
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
Next

Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\Documents\test.txt"
If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
objWriter.Write(sb.ToString()) 'Use the stringbuilder here
objWriter.WriteLine()
objWriter.Close()
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
Else
    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
End If
```

Comment: I figured it out and hope it helps someone else

Comment: `item = item.Replace(" ", "")
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", item, Environment.NewLine)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space here:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
```

So you have:

```
sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", item, Environment.NewLine)
```